# How to turn off Text Layer-Name Update

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, script

In this question: [Restore Photoshop Text Layer Name Auto-Updating?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/33621/restore-photoshop-text-layer-name-auto-updating)

The asker talks about Photoshop's 'feature' of automatically updating a text layer's layer-name to the first thing you change the text content to. While their goal is to turn this 'feature' on. I want to turn it off.

Unfortunately - it's causing a huge issue for me in a script I'm writing. The script I'm using requires that the layer name be a specific string - and this 'feature' screws up that functionality after the first script run.

I'm curious if there is a way to turn off this 'feature' I was not able to find anything in the photoshop preferences or in the panel options for layers - but perhaps someone else knows more about this functionality and might be able to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **manually** rename the layer, it doesn't update when the text changes.

Simply rename the layer to your specific needs, it should then *not* update when the text on the layer changes.

Comment: I would like to add one comment to this. While this worked (eventually) I had to manually change the layer name to something else first and then back to the way I needed the layer to be named. Since my layers were all named correctly, manually renaming them the same thing did not fix this.

Ex. All the specific layers were already named "Tagline"
Manually renaming them "Tagline" did not fix this until I manually renamed them to something else and then back to "Tagline"

Comment: This comment continues with your example where the layer already has the desired name "Tagline". You want to avoid manually renaming the layer in order to run a script which renames the layer to what it is already named. OK. Could you have that script, in its earlier operations, select the layer named "Tagline" and rename it to "TaglineZ" and then, in the later operations, return to that layer and rename it to "Tagline"? Not wanting to open a can of worms, I realize many other things are taking place with the script, but it seems this might work.